# Error while updating excel sheet using xlwings with pandas dataframe

Tags: python, excel, pandas, automation, xlwings

When I run this code, the excel sheet is updated with values but I am getting the following error messages. Please help me.

```
import glob
from operator import index
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import xlwings as xw


master_file = Master.xlsm'
ytd_file = ytd_sales.xlsx'


df1 =pd.read_excel(master_file, sheet_name='Cap', header=52)
df2 = pd.read_excel(ytd_file, sheet_name= 'Sub App', header=2)

df_master_subApp = df1.head(106)
df_ytd_subApp = df2.head(55)


wb1 = xw.Book(master_file)
ws1 = wb1.sheets['Cap']
df_subApp = pd.merge(df_master_subApp, df_ytd_subApp[['Item no.', 'NS']], on='Item no.', how='left') 
    
    df_subApp["January"] = df_subApp["NS"]  # This will copy the data from 'Amount' column to 'JAN' column
    
    df_subApp.drop("NS", axis=1, inplace=True)    
    
    ws1.range('L53:L159').options(transpose = False, index=False, numbers=int).value  = df_subApp["January"]
```

Error Messages:

```
File "c:\Users\%usename%\Documents\PythonAutomation\FinMonEndReportAutomate\merge_fin_master_ytd_file.py", line 75, in <module>
    ws1.range('L53:L159').options(transpose = False, index=False, numbers=int).value  = df_subApp["January"].values # This code will fill the "January" column in master sheet
  File "C:\Users\%usename%\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 2052, in value
    conversion.write(data, self, self._options)
  File "C:\Users\%usename%\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\__init__.py", line 48, in write
    pipeline(ctx)
  File "C:\Users\%usename%\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\framework.py", line 66, in __call__
    stage(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\%usename%\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\standard.py", line 74, in __call__
    self._write_value(ctx.range, ctx.value, scalar)
  File "C:\Users\%usename%\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\xlwings\conversion\standard.py", line 62, in _write_value
    rng.raw_value = value
  File "C:\Users\%usename%\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\xlwings\main.py", line 1645, in raw_value
    self.impl.raw_value = data
  File "C:\Users\%usename%\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 859, in raw_value
    self.xl.Value = data
  File "C:\Users\%usename%\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\xlwings\_xlwindows.py", line 109, in __setattr__
    return setattr(self._inner, key, value)
  File "C:\Users\%usename%\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\site-packages\win32com\client\__init__.py", line 595, in __setattr__
    self._oleobj_.Invoke(*(args + (value,) + defArgs))
pywintypes.com_error: (-2147352567, 'Exception occurred.', (0, None, None, None, 0, -2146827284), None)
```

Comment: Did you try using `ws1.range("L53").value = df_subApp["January"]` as last line instead?

Comment: even it is throwing the same error messages. but excel sheet column in master file is getting filled. also when I tried in new workbook it is filling the data with no errors.